# How do i manage my game state simplistically? c++

Tags: c++, directx

Hi I'm new to managing game states and i am trying to change the different states using a enum list.

```
enum class GENERAL_STATE : int {
menu = 1,
gamestart = 2,
};
```

and the header class that has the method to get and set the states

```
class GameControl {
private:

GENERAL_STATE generalState;

public:

GameControl();
~GameControl();

GENERAL_STATE getGeneralState() { return generalState; }
void setGeneralState(GENERAL_STATE gens) { generalState = gens; }
};
```

i have set the pointer to control the states using

```
GameControl*    gameControl;
```

in my game loop, i've added

```
switch (gameControl->getGeneralState())
{
case GENERAL_STATE::menu :
{
                             menu1.draw();
}break;
}
```

to draw the menu screen, but somehow it crashes and brings me to this line

```
GENERAL_STATE getGeneralState() { return generalState; }
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: How did you instantiate the instance of `gameControl`?

Comment: @pSoLT Unhandled exception at 0x00382D36 in Throw Ball Game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDCD.

Comment: @user7194060 so RustyX gave you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't done so, you have to initialize the `gameControl` pointer.

For example like this:

```
GameControl*    gameControl = new GameControl();
```

But don't forget to `delete` it at the end.

Or better yet, don't use a pointer at all:

```
GameControl   gameControl;
switch (gameControl.getGeneralState())
```

But also inside `GameControl` you should initialize `generalState`.